# Why is the height of every binary search tree not O(log n)

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

Studying for an algorithms exam, and I read that the height of every BST is not O(log n). Does this fact have something to do with the tree being balanced? Is the height of every balanced BST O (log n), and unbalanced tree something else (if so what is it)?

Comment: Yes, it has to do with balanced/unbalanced. Imagine a tree where the root is the minimum item, and none of the nodes have left children. Its height would be N (the number of items).

Comment: You could say that `h = Ω(log n)`, I suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The height of *every unbalanced* BST is not `O(lg n)` because imagine a tree with keys in increasing/decreasing order, where the tree becomes skewed to one side. This happens to be the `O(n)` worst-case for an unbalanced BST where the height is equal to `n`.

On the other hand, with a balanced tree such as an AVL tree, rotations during insertion/deletion allow these trees to maintain an approximate (not perfect) `O(lg n)` height.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it because the tree is unbalanced.  Consider what happens when you insert a sorted sequence of numbers into the tree.  Each would be a child of the previous number you inserted.  The height of the tree would be O(n).